# Use SVM predict raster file in R

Tags: r, svm, r-raster

I am new to R. And I already have a SVM model in R. Right now, I have two raster image, one is the elevation, another one is the slope. The elevation and slope would be used as the predictors for SVM. And I also want to plot the results as a map.

Right now my code is as follow, but the predict for the two raster image input return all 0. It should be 0 or 1. Anything wrong?

```
library("e1071")
tornado=read.csv(file="~/Desktop/new.csv",header=TRUE,sep=",")

err<- rep(0,5)
m<-0

for (i in c(1:5)) {
 #split the data sets into testing and training
 training.indices <- sample(nrow(tornado), 1800)
 training <- rep(FALSE, nrow(tornado))
 training[training.indices] <- TRUE

 tornado.input<- tornado[training,]
 tornado.input=data.frame(tornado.input)
 tornado=data.frame(tornado)

 tornado$Sig <- factor(tornado$Sig)

 model <- svm(Sig~slope+elevation, data=tornado.input)

 pred<- predict(model, tornado[!training,] )

 ConfM1<- table(tornado$Sig[!training], pred=pred)

 err[i]<-(sum(ConfM1)-sum(diag(ConfM1)))/sum(ConfM1)

}

library("raster")
library("rgdal")
elevation <- raster("~/Desktop/elevation.tif")
slope<- raster("~/Desktop/slope.tif")
#plot(elevation)
#plot(slope)

logo <- brick(elevation, slope)

r1 <- predict(logo,model)

plot(r1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is a bit late to answer this question but I have had the same issue. The raster::predict function does not seem to provide the same output as stats:predict. 
My alternative solution is simply to extract the values from your predictor rasters (slope and elevation), then use ggplot to project the results spatially.

```
####Convert raster into dataframe
logo_df <- as.data.frame(values(logo))
logo_df[c("x","y")] <- coordinates(logo)
logo_df <- logo_df[complete.cases(logo_df),] # in case you had holes in your raster

#### predict to this new data
pred <- predict(model, logo_df, probability = T)
logo_df$svm.fit <- attr(pred, "probabilities")[,2]

###map the predictions
ggplot(logo_df, aes(x,y,fill=svm.fit)) + 
  geom_tile() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(colorRamps::matlab.like(100))) +
  coord_fixed()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem and found that when I renamed the layers of my RasterStack to be their variable names, and added the type option, it worked!

e.g.

```
names(logo)<-c("elevation","slope")
r1<-predict(logo,model,type="response")
```